# how to use Html Input button of master page in C# behined code

Tags: c#, html

hi I got a problem to use Html input button in C# codes.
I already using Html input button in asp pages and its working well but in master page my button is not working.

the html codes is :

```
<input type="button" value="ورود" id="submit" tabindex="3" onserverclick="SubmitOn_Click" runat="server" />
```

AND behind code is :

```
protected void SubmitOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserLogin UL = new UserLogin();

        UL.USER = name.Value.ToString();
        UL.PASS = password.Value.ToString();

        UL.Select(UL.USER, UL.PASS);
    }
```

anyone can help me...

Comment: There is something wrong with your post. Your Html code is blank, and I guess that the line *protected void SubmitOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { UserLogin UL = new UserLogin();* chould be part of your code.

Comment: I am presuming that SubmitOn is a button in the master page. Is your code that handles the SubmitOn.Click event in the masterpage code behind ? And how is it wired up to handle the event ?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working" ? the click handler does not fire or what? put a breakpoint in the handler and see if it gets into the function

Comment: is "not working" means that when I click on the input button which I placed in master page is not going to function but in my other pages its working well because I did not used master page

Comment: what is the mean with my HTML code is blank
yes the line protected void SubmitOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { UserLogin UL = new UserLogin();  is part of my behind code, actually its the input button behind code which I placed in master page, but its not going to this function,  the click handler does not fire